# Python NameError exception, how do I debug it?

Tags: python, debugging, nameerror

I have a Python `NameError` exception, for example:

```
>>> def test():
...   var = 123
...
>>> test()
>>> print(var)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'var' is not defined
```

What are the steps should I take to debug it? How do I fix it?

Comment: The close target was not accurate. I'm trying to give a Q&A regarding how to debug these in general (a canonical answer). I haven't found any question that is general enough and showing a step by step approach for newcomers. It is a question common enough to warranty a good canonical explanation.

Comment: Fair enough, I believe the duplicate was close but I agree that this one is more generic.

Comment: @Selcuk unfortunately the question was highly specific to the asker, containing a lot of code, and the answer solved his specific case. It will be hard for a newcomer to understand from it. I'd be happy for any additional suggestions :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 1 - Find out where was the variable used:

Read the `NameError` exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'var' is not defined
```

The last line contains the name of the variable, in this case `var`. Make sure the spelling is correct and you made no mistake.

Right above the `NameError`, you can see the file name and the line number. This is the location where you tried to use the variable.

### Step 2 - Figure out where was the variable defined:

Look for a `var =`  or any function which contains `var` as the argument:

```
def func(var):
    ...
```

Where is the variable you're trying to use? Where does it exist?

Try finding that name in all of your Python files using `ctrl+f` in Windows or `cmd+f` in Mac.

### Step 3 - Try to understand the scoping rules:

- #### If the variable was defined in a function:

  Am I in the same function?

  ```
  def test():
      var = 1

  print(var)  # This will not work.

  def test2():
      print(var)  # This will not work either.
  ```

  If you're not in the same function, try fixing by returning the variable:

  ```
  def test():
      var = 1
      return var

  var = test()

  print(var)  # This will work
  ```

  or by accepting the variable as an argument:

  ```
  var = test()

  def test2(x):  # var is now named 'x'
      print(x)  

  test2(var)
  ```

  You can also return multiple variables:

  ```
  def test():
       var1 = "hello"
       var2 = "world" 
       return var1, var2
  var1, var2 = test()
  print(var1, var2)  # Prints hello world.
  ```

  If you are in the same function or using a `global`, did you use `if` statements and never entered them? Maybe an exception was thrown and you suppressed?

  ```
  def test():
       if False:  # Never true
           var = 123
       print(var)  # This will not work

  def test2():
       try:
           2/0  # Throws an error
           var = 123
       except:
           pass
       print (var)  # This will not work
  ```
- #### If the variable was defined in the class:

  ```
  class Test:
      var = 123
      def func(self):
          print(var)  # This will not work
  ```

  Make sure you use `self` to access it:

  ```
  class Test:
      var = 123
      def func(self):
          print(self.var)  # This will work
  ```

  pass it using a default parameter:

  ```
  class Test:
      var = 123
      def func(self, param=var):
          print(param)
  ```

  or access it using the instance:

  ```
  class Test:
      var = 123
      def func(self, param=var):
          print(param)
  inst = Test()
  inst.var  # This will work
  inst.func()  # This will work
  ```
- #### If the variable is the name of a function or class:

  Make sure you define before using it:

  ```
  func()
  def func():  # This will not work
      pass
  ```
- #### If you can't find it or it's not in the same file:

  Are you trying to import it and forgot?

  ```
  import operator
  itemgetter # This will not work
  operator.itemgetter  # This will work
  ```

  Are you sure you spelled it correctly? Remember, Python is case-sensitive!

For more information about scoping, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/1658617).

If everything failed and you still haven't found your answer, you're always welcome to open a question and ask, or write in the comments of your existing stackoverflow question.

Read the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648) an provide a minimal example - make sure your example contains enough code to see the location where the variable is defined, and where it is used, but not too much code as it will be hard to understand.